# Extracting sub arrays from a two dimensional array for each element and displaying them in a table using KnockoutJS

Tags: php, arrays, knockout.js

I have used below code in PHP to extract data from MySQL :

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT `inn_lay_list`, `inner_layer` FROM `da_customer_auto_inner` 
where `mpcode` = 'qf017'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data1 = $row['inn_lay_list'];
    $data2 = $row['inner_layer'];
}

$parts1 = explode(';',$data1);
$parts2 = explode(';',$data2);
$layer_cnt = count($parts1);
$array_inner = array_chunk($parts2, 8);

echo json_encode($parts1);
echo json_encode($array_inner);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I obtained the result as:

["001","011","021","031"]

[["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"], ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"], ["21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28"],[31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38"]]

Here for each element in first array there is a sub array in the second array(two dimensional array).
Now I want to display this in HTML page using a table. I am trying to use KnockoutJS “foreach” option with a named template:

```
<script>
function MyViewModel() {
    this.layer = [{
        name: "<?=@$parts1[0]?>",
        layer_data: "<?=@$array_inner[0]?>"
    },
    {
        name: "<?=@$parts1[1]?>",
        layer_data: "<?=@$array_inner[1]?>"
    },
    {
        name: "<?=@$parts1[2]?>",
        layer_data: "<?=@$array_inner[2]?>"
    },
    {
        name: "<?=@$parts1[3]?>",
        layer_data: "<?=@$array_inner[3]?>"
    }]
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Layer</td>
      <td>P2P</td>
      <td>P2T</td>
      <td>T2T</td>
      <td>Track Width</td>
      <td>PTH To Cu</td>
      <td>NPTH To Cu</td>
      <td>PTH AR</td>
      <td>Via AR</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template:{name:'layer-template', foreach:layer}"> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/html" id="layer-template">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[0]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[1]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[2]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[3]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[4]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[5]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[6]"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: layer_data[7]"></td>
</tr>
</script>
```

I want my output as below :

[image: Output]

Comment: `$arr[0]` . That's all

Comment: $array=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]; Then $array[0];

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code to help you improve it.

Comment: $arr[0]  is array . your trying to echo it . you can't echo the array . try like  this $layer_data =  implode(',',$arr[0]); @DeveshN.

Comment: $array[0] first key of your main array

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following :

```
$array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
$array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

use `current()` function returns the value of the current element in an array.

```
<?php

$array=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

var_dump(current($array));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple do this:

```
$array=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]; 
print_r($array[0]);

If you want read all:
foreach($array as $arr){
print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: As you commented from <?=@$arr[0] ?> in this you should remove the @ @Devesh N.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-shift.php).

```
$tab = array(array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9));
$b = array_shift($tab);
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question that array is in json format,So first of all you need to decode that json to array using json_decode(). then you can directly use $array[0].